# Com Interop Structure Definition Does Not Match Memory Layout

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop

There is a struct defined in a COM header (vds.h):

```
typedef struct _VDS_DISK_EXTENT
{
    // A Guid
    VDS_OBJECT_ID diskId;
    // An Enum, with the largest defined value 0x7FFF
    VDS_DISK_EXTENT_TYPE type;
    ULONGLONG ullOffset;
    ULONGLONG ullSize;
    // Guid
    VDS_OBJECT_ID volumeId;
    //Guid
    VDS_OBJECT_ID plexId;
    ULONG memberIdx;
} VDS_DISK_EXTENT;
```

I've annotated the types of some of the fields. Based on this header definition, the struct appears to be 72 bytes large. However, when I marshal it in C# (I get an IntPtr to an array of these structs) and look at the memory where the IntPtr indicates, I see this:

```
0x01717A50  a8 c5 af 28 37 e1 0d 43  -> diskId
0x01717A58  b0 87 e2 ef 94 5f 9f 27  -> diskId
0x01717A60  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  -> first 4 bytes are extent type, second 4?
0x01717A68  00 00 70 23 00 00 00 00  -> offset
0x01717A70  00 00 50 4d 74 00 00 00  -> size
0x01717A78  38 3c 22 26 e9 de df 44  -> volumeId
0x01717A80  81 f3 ba ee af e2 ad 2b  -> volumeId
0x01717A88  48 98 78 bb 7f dd bc 41  -> plexId
0x01717A90  94 17 db d2 86 01 54 ce  -> plexId
0x01717A98  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  -> first 4 bytes are membderIdx, second 4?
```

As you can see, there are 2 4 byte areas that are unaccounted for. The c++ enum is declared like `typedef enum _VDS_DISK_EXTENT_TYPE {` so I don't think it's 8 bytes. Same with the memberIdx, it's declared as a ULONG, so it's 4 bytes. Where is this padding defined or where are the offsets for each field defined? It makes it nearly impossible to use the objects from this com assembly if I have to view each one in memory and figure out where the real boundaries between fields are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a case of structure member alignment. Specifically, this struct was compiled with an alignment of 8 bytes, which is the default for Visual C++. Note that each member begins on an 8-byte boundary. If there were consecutive members that were smaller than 8 bytes (for example, two consecutive `ULONG`s), you wouldn't see the extra padding on the first `ULONG` (because 4-byte members can be aligned on 4-byte boundaries when using an alignment value >= 4). But since you've got a `ULONG` followed by a `ULONGLONG`, the `ULONG` member is padded so that the following `ULONGLONG` member is aligned on the 8-byte boundary (because 8-byte members canNOT be aligned on 4-byte boundaries).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh3e3fd0.aspx